# find_element(By)にURLによって変わる要素を入れたい

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

以下のような２つのデータフレームから各URLのIDと一致するtxtを抜き出して`find_element(By.LINK_TEXT)`に入れ込むようなことは可能でしょうか？df2のtxt部分は重複する場合もあります。よろしくお願い致します。

---

**df1:**

```
URL ID
aaa 1
bbb 2
ccc 3
ddd 4
... ...
```

**df2:**

```
ID txt
1  xxx
2  yyy
3  zzz
4  xxx
... ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df1`と`df2`を[merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)して結合することで、IDが一致するtxtを抜き出すことができます。
下記サンプルコードの`merge_sample`関数では、結合後のデータフレームから[iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)を使ってURLとtxtを1行ずつ読み込んで処理しています。

**サンプルコード**

```
def merge_sample(df1, df2):
    # df1とdf2をマージする
    df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["ID"], how="inner")
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        # df1のURLを呼び出す
        print(f'driver.get("{row["URL"]}")')
        # df2のtxtを取得する
        print(f'driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "{row["txt"]}")')

# 前準備
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s1 = """ 
URL ID
aaa 1
bbb 2
ccc 3
ddd 4
""" 
io1 = StringIO(s1)
df1 = pd.read_csv(io1, sep=" ")

s2 = """ 
ID txt
1 xxx
2 yyy
3 zzz
4 xxx
""" 
io2 = StringIO(s2)
df2 = pd.read_csv(io2, sep=" ")

merge_sample(df1, df2)
```

**実行結果**

```
driver.get("aaa")
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "xxx")
driver.get("bbb")
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "yyy")
driver.get("ccc")
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "zzz")
driver.get("ddd")
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "xxx")
```